# I can not for the life of me figure out how to pixelate multiple images and get the pixel data

Tags: javascript, html

This keeps returning pixel data that is just empty values I think it’s because the image is not loading before hand but I have to pass info into the function and idk if that is why it’s causing that.
I have tried multiple ways of formatting it but I don’t think that’s the issue and I cant find any topics that go into this specifically.
What I want is there to be a 32x32 pixel data for each that is not just empty values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    img {
      height: 128px;
      width: 128px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="image1" src="https://picsum.photos/128">
  <img id="image2" src="https://picsum.photos/128">
  <form method="post" id="new">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
<script>
  function rgba2hex(orig) {
    rgb = orig.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/^rgba?\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),?([^,\s)]+)?/i),
      hex = rgb ? (rgb[1] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) + (rgb[2] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) + (rgb[3] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) : orig;
    a = (rgb[4] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1)
    hex = hex + a;
    return hex;
  }
  var element = document.getElementById("new");
  var imageArray = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  var img1A = [];
  var cA = [];
  var ctxA = [];
  for (n = 0; n < imageArray.length; n++) {
    cA[n] = document.createElement("canvas");
    ctxA[n] = cA[n].getContext('2d');
    img1A[n] = new Image();
    img1A[n].src = imageArray[n].src;
    img1A[n].onload = pixelate(cA[n], ctxA[n], img1A[n], n, imageArray[n]);

    function pixelate(c, ctx, img1, n, imageX) {
      imageX.remove();
      w = 128;
      h = 128;
      c.width = w;
      c.height = h;
      ctx.drawImage(imageX, 0, 0);
      var pixelArr = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h).data;
      sample_size = 4;
      var log = {};
      for (let y = 0; y < h; y += sample_size) {
        log[y / 4] = {};
        for (let x = 0; x < w; x += sample_size) {
          let p = (x + (y * w)) * 4;
          ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + pixelArr[p] + "," + pixelArr[p + 1] + "," + pixelArr[p + 2] + "," + pixelArr[p + 3] + ")";
          ctx.fillRect(x, y, sample_size, sample_size);
          log[y / 4][x / 4] = "#" + rgba2hex("rgba(" + pixelArr[p] + "," + pixelArr[p + 1] + "," + pixelArr[p + 2] + "," + pixelArr[p + 3] + ")");
        }
      }
      var hexJson = {};
      hexJson.pixel_json = {};
      for (a in log) {
        for (b in log[a]) {
          var hex = log[a][b];
          var coord = {};
          coord.x = parseInt(b);
          coord.y = parseInt(a);
          if (hexJson.pixel_json[hex] == null) {
            hexJson.pixel_json[hex] = []
          }
          hexJson.pixel_json[hex].push(coord);
        }
      }
      var para = document.createElement("input");
      para.name = "pixelData" + n;
      para.type = "hidden";
      para.value = JSON.stringify(hexJson);
      element.appendChild(para);
      let img2 = new Image();
      img2.src = c.toDataURL("image/png");
      img2.width = 128;
      document.body.appendChild(img2);
    };
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI you misspelled height as `hieght`. Can you change this snippet to use [example images](https://picsum.photos/)?

Comment: You generally cannot get pixel data from images you load from a different domain.

Comment: I know I’m trying to get pixel data from images the user uploads though so no crossOrigin shenanigans are at fault.